# the number of subgroups of $S_p$ for prime p which have order p

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to do this without using Sylow theorems. I was wondering if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groups of prime order are cyclic. Every cyclic group of prime order $p$ has $p-1$ generators.

Therefore, the function

$$ \{\textrm{elements of order }p\}\to\{\textrm{subgroups of order }p\}$$

given by $\pi\mapsto\langle \pi\rangle$ is a $(p-1)$-to-$1$ mapping.

Any permutation has a disjoint cycle representation, and its order is the lcm of the cycle lengths, so any element in $S_p$ of order $p$ must be a $p$-cycle $(a_1\,a_2\,\cdots\,a_p)$. Thus the elements of order $p$ are precisely those elements with this cycle type.

A general fact about permutations is how conjugation affects cycles:

$$ \pi(a_1\,a_2\,\cdots\,a_p)\pi^{-1}=(\pi(a_1)\,\pi(a_2)\,\cdots\,\pi(a_p)). \tag{$\circ$}$$

(This of course applies with any length cycle, and hence with whole disjoint cycle representations.)

Thus, the collection of elements of order $p$, i.e. of all permutations with this cycle type, form a single conjugacy class in $S_p$. One canonical representative is $t=(1\,2\,\cdots\,p)$. Any conjugacy class can be thought of as an orbit of a group action if we interpret $S_p$ as acting on itself by conjugation, so by the orbit stabilizer theorem the size of the conjugacy class is the index of the stabilizer, in other words the centralizer $C_{S_p}(t)$.

Note that $(a_1\,a_2\,\cdots\,a_p)=(b_1\,b_2\,\cdots\,b_p)$ if and only if $b_1,\cdots,b_p$ are the same numbers as $a_1,\cdots,a_p$ but possibly *cycled*. The permutations which cycle the entries of $t$ are precisely the elements of $\langle t\rangle$. Therefore we have

$$[S_p:\langle t\rangle]=(p-1)!$$

elements of order $p$, in which case there are

$$\frac{(p-1)!}{(p-1)}=(p-2)! $$

subgroups of order $p$.

Comment: I don't understand why any element of $S_p$ has order p can you explain that more ?

Comment: What do you mean by  (p−1)-to-1 mapping ?

Comment: @Adeek I did not say every element of $S_p$ has order $p$. A function $f:X\to Y$ is said to be $n$-to-$1$ if for every $y\in Y$, there are exactly $n$ elements of $X$ which map to it (i.e. the preimage $f^{-1}(y)$ has size $n$).

Comment: I mean why is every element of $S_p$ of order p is a p-cycle ?

Comment: Every element $\pi\in S_p$ can be written as a product of disjoint cycles of lengths $\ell_1,\cdots,\ell_k$. The lengths all add up to $p$ (if you include $1$-cycles), so $\ell_1+\cdots+\ell_k=p$. If any of $\ell_1,\cdots,\ell_p$ is $<p$, then they are all $<p$, in which case the order of $\pi$, which is the lcm of $\ell_1,\cdots,\ell_p$, will not be divisible by $p$. So for $\pi$ to have order $p$, all $\ell_i$'s are $p$ or bigger, which forces there to be only one cycle and it must have length $p$.

Comment: okay I understand thank you !!